# Somehow, I have got 2 accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

Last week I posted a question on SharePoint.stackexchange.com, and today I couldn't find my question.
As it turns out, i found the question on a duplicate account.
So apparently, I'm here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/304/
and here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/568

The most logical explanation would be that I *could* have used 2 different OpenID accounts, but I have no recollection of doing that.

Is there any way of merging the two accounts?
(The /568 should be the one and only)

Answer (score 1):

Magnus, I merged your 304 account with the 568 master account. You should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I also do. 1884 & 2160. Could those be merged? Thanks!

Edit: I did notice that my old account from SPO had some votes and points associated, but those don't appear under the account. Were those somehow merged in to this account (which is a completely new account on this site)

Comment: Was this taken care of for you? I don't see those other users. Sorry.. wasn't watching the old posts. :(

Comment: Yes it was. It was done in a chat session...I think I had linked the wrong 2nd account here too. Oops. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also need that. Can you merge 2853 with 613?

Thanks!

Comment: Done! For anyone else who stumbles across this.. just make a new post tagged with [tag:support]

Comment: thanks Kit! I appreciate it.